# an issue caused by rounding when converting seconds to minutes

Tags: python

A quick demonstration of my little problem. It might sound like a newbie question, but I need to be sure to deliver correct code, that's why I decided to ask anyway.

```
def minsec(sec):
    m, s = divmod(sec, 60) 
    print(f"{int(m)}m {s:.2f}s")

minsec(59.99)   # 0m 59.99s OK
minsec(59.999)  # 0m 60.00s !!! I definitely want 1m 0.00s
```

My first thought was if the seconds part is above 59.995 I should add 0.005. Or I should round every value to 2 decimal places as the first step. In the real program the number of decimal place is variable, but that is manageable. The next idea was to check if the resulting string is starting with "60" seconds and fix that when it happens. Or is there a better algorithm?

Comment: As far as I can guess, that is done by `{s:.2f}s` format statement, maybe round off to 2 digits with builtin function `round` before feeding it into formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line at the top of your function:

```
sec = round(sec, 2)
```

Comment: There seems to be a consensus for this option.

Answer (score 0):

You could allow rounding to take place ahead of your divmod call

```
def minsec(sec):
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    m, s = divmod(sec, 60) 
    print(f"{int(m)}m {s:.2f}s")
```

Comment: Better to just call `round` directly instead of doing it as a side effect of string formatting and then converting it back to a float.

Answer (score 0):

Update the statement `m, s = divmod(sec, 60)` to:

```
m, s = divmod(round(sec, 2), 60)
```

This will give the desired output and does not needs much calculations.